# Click a Button Issue [clickButton is not a function] [discord.js-selfbot-v13]

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, discord.js, discord-buttons

```
const { Client, clickButton } = require('discord.js-selfbot-v13');
const client = new Client({
    checkUpdate: false,
});

client.on('ready', async () => {
    const channelId = '1190781950944886870';
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
  
    if (channel) {
      console.log(`Channel found: ${channel.name}`);
      const message_id = await channel.sendSlash('999736048596816014', 'config channel', channelId);
      console.log('Slash Command Sent! | '+message_id)
      await message_id.clickButton()
    } else {
      console.error('Channel not found.');
    }
  });

client.login('my token');
```

Error:

```
await message_id.clickButton()
                       ^

TypeError: message_id.clickButton is not a function
```

I don't know why it says that `.clickButton` is not an function, the [Docs](https://github.com/aiko-chan-ai/discord.js-selfbot-v13/blob/main/Document/Message.md) say otherwise...

Comment: Are you sure this method is implemented for a slash reply message ?

Comment: The slash part works, just the button clicking part doesn't work

Comment: I mean, the object returned by the sendSlash method is not a Message object but a InteractionResponse object. So it doesn't have a clickButton method. See [documentation](https://github.com/aiko-chan-ai/discord.js-selfbot-v13/blob/f025065a63145dfcc85c912ba0acb4cbe9e55696/typings/index.d.ts#L4283) here.

Comment: Could you please provide code that will fix the issue? I don't use Javascript on a daily basis.